# How to debug Golang fault when running go test --race on package?

Tags: go, segmentation-fault

So I'm receiving a fault when running `go test --race my/package/ya`.  The output looks like this:

```
unexpected fault address 0x200015a490e0
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x200015a490e0 pc=0x47399ac]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw(0x0, 0xc820000180)
    /opt/go1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:530 +0x90 fp=0x7fff5fbfeb80 sp=0x7fff5fbfeb68

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /opt/go1.6/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1
```

I've tried catching this fault in a TestMain, but apparently my TestMain doesn't get called.  I've tried using -trace to generate a trace file, but the file never is written although the testing file pkg.out is written.  I'm not entirely sure where to go from here since the output doesn't really provide many hints.  I suppose I can attempt gdb and delve, but haven't had luck with either of those in the past.

I'm wondering if there is something else to consider?

Additional notes:  this fault only occurs when the --race flag is present.  Go 1.6 darwin/amd64.

Comment: You can't recover from a segfault. Does your package or any of its dependencies use cgo?

Comment: Yeah, it uses zmq4.

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace? (you can try adding `GOTRACEBACK=all` or `system`). Is the fault address the same every time?

Comment: Yeah, that's the entire stack trace -- I'll try `GOTRACEBACK=all` or `system`.  And yeah same fault address every time.

Comment: If you can figure out where the `0x200015a490e0` value comes from, it may help trace back to the problem. I think something in the C code (zmq4) is trying to dereference that address.

Comment: Fwiw, the same code compiles, and tests run without errors on centos7 just fine.  It may be a Mac thing.

Answer (score 0):

(Warming up this really old question)

Simply upgrade to Go `1.20` (see [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/54291)).

For reference, the errors are (taken from issue):

- In version `1.19`:

  ```
  syscall.ptrace: nosplit stack over 792 byte limit
  syscall.ptrace<1>
     grows 128 bytes, calls syscall.ptrace1<1>
  [...]
  ```
- In version `1.18.5`

  ```
  runtime.fatalthrow: nosplit stack overflow
       792 assumed on entry to syscall.ptrace<1> (nosplit)
  [...]
  ```